# Can I create a Hashtable using a list of Strings as keys , and a list of Objects as values?

Tags: java, csv, object, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to create a hashtable of employees, and I need some help. I have a list of objects of employees (People), and a list of strings of their usernames (UsersToCompare). I was wondering if there was a simple way to set the list of strings (UsersToCompare) as the keys in a hashtable, and the list of objects (People) as the values? This is the code I'm currently working on:

```
`public class HashTable {
static List<String> UsersToCompare = new ArrayList<String>();
static List<Entry> People = new ArrayList<>();
Hashtable<String, Object> theTable;
    public void readFromFile() {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String csvFile = "employee_data.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] Labels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                UsersToCompare.add(Labels[0]);
                Entry entry = new Entry(Labels[0], Labels[1], Labels[2], Labels[3], Labels[4], Labels[5], Labels[6],
                        Labels[7]);
                People.add(entry);
//              theTable.put(Labels[0], entry);   ////null pointer exception
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Labels[0] is the first column of the CSV file, where I retrieve usernames. Both the lists UsersToCompare and People are filled with what I'd like to use as values and keys, I just don't know how to set them properly. Above you can see I tried to put them in while reading the file, but I got a null pointer exception. Also, entry is the name of the object before I put them into the list of people. There are so many string separations because it has everything from username, name, race, gender, SSN, etc..

Comment: You have to initialize the table field, the same way you initialized the lists. Then putting something into the list will work.

Comment: wow, silly mistake. Thank you @dunni!